# Why can I access MongoDB remotely if bind_ip is set to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: mongodb, security, configuration, ip

In `mongod.conf`, I see that `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1`, which is the localhost interface. According to the docs:

> Because production MongoDB instances need to be accessible from
>   multiple database servers, it is important to bind MongoDB to multiple
>   interfaces that are accessible from your application servers.

Doesn't that imply that I should only have access from a local machine since that is the only IP I specified? However, I can definitely access the database remotely. Am I not understanding this setting correctly?

Comment: If you have 'bind_ip = 127.0.0.1' in mongod.conf file then mongodb will accept connection from the same machine only. You wont be able to connect to the mongodb server from any other machine. Are you sure you restarted mongodb after changing the config file?

Comment: @AbhayPS Yes, I restarted both machines several times. I had this config file for a long time and have not edited it recently. I was reviewing it for security purposes when I noticed that.

Comment: Are you sure that the mongodb uses config file you are checking? May be, your mongodb is picking up config from some other file and you are checking the wrong config file.

Comment: @AbhayPS Is there a way to check if it's using some other config file? I am not specifying it. Isn't that the default one?

Comment: Okay. How do you run mongodb? Which operating system?

Answer (score -3):

bind_ip=127.0.0.1 means only your localhost can access it,if you want that your db can be access by any other server or computer make this line as:-
 **#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1**